# Asynchronous logging into database in biztalk to speed up response

Tags: biztalk

I'd like to speed up response time in my application which have a lot of side logging operations to DB. Every request/response is putting to DB via calling helper orchiestration that manage to store request/response messages.

In order to figure it out I wrote simple app that invokes WCF service , calls asynchronous DB logging orchiestration and should return response but it doesn't. I have no response but logging works well. I suppose mixing synchronous orchiestrations with asynchronous ones isn't that simple . Can someone guide me if it is possibile to do in Biztalk?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a .NET helper class where you leverage a `BackgroundWorker`  and put your logging logic inside a `DoWorkEventHandler`, then run it as `RunWorkerAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent whole day on looking for errors in my test app it turns out that newest version of SoapUI 5.5.0 has been showing response in RAW rather than in XML tab!

I managed to store logs in asynchronous way and save about 1,5s per request shorten time from 4,5 to 3s.

Answer (score 0):

Well...the way you speed up you processing while logging is **to not log, especially custom logging or archiving**.  This is nothing more than an additional processing tax because...

BizTalk already does this out of the box.  I've never seen a custom logging/archiving solution that adds anything beyond what BizTalk Server already does.

So, if you properly configure Tracking and add useful search fields, you've covered 99.9% of logging use cases.

Comment: Could You guide me more or elaborate about "properly configuration of  Tracking and add useful search fields". I found tracking to be a lot of messy and contains a lot of needless messages plus cause much tracking database growth. In my company, we avoid using tracking because of that facts.

Comment: @PiotrGrudzień You can start here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32616.biztalk-archiving-the-biztalk-way.aspx.  The only 'trick' is to only track what you need.  The Tracking DB has to be maintained just like any other database.  A custom solution will *always* be more work and messier than Tracking.  Sorry to say but it seems by avoiding Tracking, you've just created more problems. :(

Answer (score 0):

Logging and Archiving is pretty common in integration solutions. In fact it is one of the needs for end to end monitoring. But using helper orchestration sounds too much for this purpose. You can make use of BAM to log the request responses which is much faster specially when you use Buffered event streams.Depending on your needs you can also make use of products such as Atomic Scope from BizTalk360.